# Memory requirements for FFT on STM32F103C8

Tags: fft

I have a limited system and would like to implement FFT within STM32F103C8 without any extra memory buffers.

So I want to know how many memories are needed to implement if I have 2592x1944x8bit size's one image?

Actually, I want to have a process such as

Origial image ---> FFT ---> Blur ---> IFFT ---> Modified image
The blur(Gaussian) size is quite a bit huge size. 60x60~90x90 variable.

What is the memory requirements for FFT on STM32F103C8 ?

The reason of why I pick this way up is 60x60~90x90 gaussian blur need a huge memory to process to blur. and  I found FFT blur processing from google, so this is the reason.

Comment: The micro system STM32F103C8 has about 64 kB of flash memory. I wonder how do you fit the image of 2592x1944 (about 5 MBytes) into this system ?

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks for reply, BTW  I think you want to say I need to have a full  memory which has one image size (2592x1944) about 5 Mbytes. I'm not expert, so I'm wondering usually how do this do to resolve this kind of problems?

Comment: Yes you think right. A standard FFT based filtering requires the whole image to be present in memory.

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks BTW, Would you please introduce me the FFT algorithm for dummies like me.. I want to understand the algorithm but I'm not expert and familiar with math so I need something more

Comment: you can look for FFT butterfly implementations. Start form DSP.se